# Remember last n items in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, queue

I have some code to randomly highlight one name from a list (this works - see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ErhkC/1/)):

```
function pickRandom() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  $('.stname').css('background','none').eq(random).css('background','yellow');
}
```

But I'd like to make sure that the same names don't come up over and over. So I intend to remember the last 3 chosen indexes as a blacklist:

```
var recentlyAsked = new Array();
function pickRandom() {
  var random;
  do {
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  } while ($.inArray(random,recentlyAsked));
  recentlyAsked.push(random);
  if (recentlyAsked.length >= 4) recentlyAsked.shift();
  $('.stname').css('background','none').eq(random).css('background','yellow');
}
```

This is not working; see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U6tHc/3/). **Warning:** it causes the browser to hang.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Your browser hangs because the loop does not stop. The warning is actually pretty useful, but I doubt anyone will see the fiddle you linked to :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
do {
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  } while ($.inArray(random,recentlyAsked));
```

Runs forever because `inArray` returns `-1` when an item is not found in the array, which is a truthy value. `0` is the only number that is a falsy value. Your array is initially empty so nothing is found.

Fix it with :

```
do {
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  } while ($.inArray(random,recentlyAsked) > -1);
```

This will stop when it returns `-1`(not found)

Answer (score 1):

```
var ids=['a','b','c'];
var old=['d','e','f'];//At the beginning this will need populated with 3 random values
var ran=Math.floor(Math.random() * ids.length);
var ele=ids.splice(ran,1);
old.push(ele);
ids.push(old.shift());
highlight(ele);
```

Here is a slightly alternative way to do what you want.  The idea is just remove chosen elements and then add it back in to the original array.

Answer (score 1):

Just thought I would throw my code out there:

```
var randomArray = new Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
var pastArray = new Array();

function pickRandom() {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomArray.length);
    $('.stname').css('background', 'none').eq(randomArray[random]).css('background', 'yellow');

    if (pastArray.length < 3) {
        pastArray.unshift(randomArray[random]);
        randomArray.splice(random, 1);
    } else {
        pastArray.unshift(randomArray[random]);
        randomArray.splice(random, 1, pastArray.pop());
    }
    console.log("possible values: [" + randomArray + "]");
    console.log("past values: [" + pastArray + "]");
}
```

Values are moved back and forth from the current and past values. There is no need to prepopulate values as 'past', so it starts out truly random.